# php proxy directory

Tags: php, proxy, webserver

Lets say we got a directory on a server Loacated Really FAR

server1.{domainUS}/maindir/

but i have a **main** server

{domain.UK}

i will like to create a subdomain pointed to my **main** Server instead of pointing it to my other server `server1.{domainUS}` because my remote server **only**  allows http to be transmitted to via **main** server.... 
so i need a PHP Proxy like script that forwards the compleate dir to the **main** server

Example..

```
server1.{domainUS}/maindir/testube/testfile.html <==test file
proxy.{domain.UK}/testube/testfile.html  <==test file
```

Example2, i also need it to work nicely with php queries ect..

```
server1.{domainUS}/maindir/testube/testfile <==test php document
proxy.{domain.UK}/testube/testfile  <==test php document
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your server config for `server1.{domainUS}` (assuming Apache):

```
<Directory "maindir/">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ http://google.com/%{PATH_INFO}
</Directory>
```

Or if you can't change the config, you can put the contents of the `Directory` tag inside an `.htaccess` file in `maindir`.